# How to improve some Symfony code using session

Tags: php, symfony, session, shopping-cart

I'm writing a shoes shop website using sessions in Symfony for PHP. I have a shopping cart where I can add some products. I use variable $shoesid here. I created a controller to work with Cart which stores 3 functions: display cart, add item to cart and remove item from cart.

Here's a function to add a shoe to shopping cart.

```
/**
 * @Route("/cart/add/{shoesid}", name="cartAdd")
 */
public function add($shoesid, SessionInterface $session)
{
    $cart = $session->get('cart', []);

    if(!empty($cart[$shoesid])) {
        $cart[$shoesid]++;
    } else {
        $cart[$shoesid] = 1;
    }

    $session->set('cart', $cart);
    return $this->redirectToRoute('cart');
}
```

Here's a function to display a cart

```
/**
     * @Route("/cart", name="cart")
     */
    public function index(SessionInterface $session, ShoesRepository $shoesRepository, CountriesRepository $countriesRepository)
    {
        $cart = $session->get('cart', []);
        $cartWithData = [];

        foreach($cart as $shoesid => $quantity)
        {
            $cartWithData[] = [
                'shoe' => $shoesRepository->shoeDescr($shoesid),
                'shoePrice' => $shoesRepository->find($shoesid),
                'quantity' => $quantity
            ];
        }
        
        $total=0;
        $delivery=20;

        foreach($cartWithData as $item) 
        {
            $totalItem = $item['shoePrice']->getShoesPrice()*$item['quantity'];
            $total += $totalItem;
            
        }

        $countries = $countriesRepository->findBy(array(), array('countryname' => 'asc'));
        // dd($cartWithData);
        return $this->render('cart/index.html.twig', [
            'items' => $cartWithData,
            'total' => $total,
            'delivery' => $delivery,
            'countries' => $countries
            // 'controller_name' => 'CartController',
        ]);
    }
```

Here's a function which deletes an item from cart:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/cart/remove/{shoesid}", name="cartRemove")
     */
    public function remove($shoesid, SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $cart = $session->get('cart', []);

        if(!empty($cart[$shoesid])){
            unset($cart[$shoesid]);
        }
        $session->set('cart', $cart);

        return $this->redirectToRoute('cart');
    }
}
```

Now I need to add a variable $sizeid to pass a size of selected item, but I don't know how to do that. I tried to modify code for adding item to cart like this:

```
public function add($shoesid, $sizeid, SessionInterface $session, StockRepository $stockRepository)
    {
        $cart = $session->get('cart', []);

        if(!empty($cart[$shoesid[$sizeid]])) {
            $cart[$shoesid[$sizeid]]++;
        } else {
            $cart[$shoesid[$sizeid]] = 1;
        }

        $session->set('cart', $cart);
        dd($session->get('cart'));
    }
```

But it's wrong and I get the next exception:

> Notice: Uninitialized string offset

I want to get JSON messages like this (or something like this):

> 40001 => 40 => 2

where the first value is shoesid, the second one is sizeid and the last one is quantity [count of shoesid] (now I can get only shoesid and quantity)

What code changes do I need?

Answer (score 0):

If example cart looks like this

```
$cart = ['40001' => ['40' => 2], '40002' => ['40' => 1]];
```

Then you check if shoe is in cart and add accordingly - notice that brackets are placed like that

```
$cart [$shoeId] [$sizeId]
```

so your code should look like

```
if(!empty($cart[$shoesid][$sizeid])) {
    $cart[$shoesid][$sizeid]++;
} else {
    $cart[$shoesid][$sizeid] = 1;
}
```

If it's possible to have different shoe sizes in cart for the same shoeid, e.g.

```
'40001' => ['40'=> 2, '38' => 1]
```

then you should change your remove method accordingly, because now you just remove all cart entries for particular shoeid, so the above sizes 40 and 38 would be removed from cart all at once. You should rather do

```
/**
 * @Route("/cart/remove/{shoesid}/{sizeid}", name="cartRemove")
 */
public function remove($shoesid, $sizeid = null, SessionInterface $session)
{
    $cart = $session->get('cart', []);

    if(!empty($cart[$shoesid])){
        if($sizeid){
           unset($cart[$shoesid][$sizeid]);
        } else {
            unset($cart[$shoesid]);
        }
    }
    $session->set('cart', $cart);

    return $this->redirectToRoute('cart');
}
```

This way you can either remove only one size or all of them at once